# how to print log for camera action

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk

In my project i tried to implement camera action in onReceive method. While clicking on camera icon can we print log . i tried it in broadcast receiver. but i cant able to get the result.i attached my piece of code here.

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON)) {

            Log.e("cam0","cam");
        //Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //context.startService(cameraIntent);
   // startActivity(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

is it possible to print log for that. Im cracking my head still i cant find the result. Looking for help in this situation. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filter for Logcat so that every log with a specific TAG gets grouped together for quick and easy viewing. Just open up the Logcat view and to the left there is a button (green plus sign) for adding new filters.

And its convention to declare a constant in the class to be used as a log tag, for example `private static final string TAG = TAG_camActivity`.

If the log isn't showing up then that if statement in all likelihood isn't being evaluated to true.